# How can I follow an Area 51 proposal already in the commit phase when my commitments are full?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, following-proposal

How can I follow an Area 51 proposal already in the commit phase when my commitments are full? I can only commit to 3 proposals and while I await their betas I can't commit to any more, so I'd like to follow them instead so I can get notifications and have them appear on my home page to know when they go to beta. If I had followed them before they crossed the line, my following would carry forward, but if I only come upon them afterwords, I see no way to follow them at this late point.

Please add a way to follow proposals in the commit phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always click the "definition" tab ([example](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612?phase=definition)) on a proposal to go back to how it looked in the definition phase, and then click the follow link there

[image: Screenshot of definition tab]

Comment: Great thanks, I wonder if this should some how be refactored in the interface since it was not that obvious to find.  Perhaps replicating the follow choice in the commitment section.